# How to find a button with custom attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a button called `"Send Enquiry"` with custom attribute as `"provider-id"`, after clicking that `button` a `fancybox` opens, which has form to send enquiry.

What I want is as soon as the enquiry is sent, the `button` `"Send Enquiry"` on that page should be `disabled`.(the one that opened `fancybox`)

here's the code for button

```
<a class='btn btn-orange' provider-id='$row->provider_id' href='#EnquiryForm' id='btnSend' onclick='fillenquiry(this)'>Send Enquiry</a></div>
```

everything is working fine, I just want to `disable` that `button`, after sending enquiry

NOTE: actually there are multiple buttons with the same id,so I have to put the custom attribute as `"provider-id"`.

Comment: ID of an element must be unique

Comment: `$('#btnSend').attr("disabled", true);`

Comment: @AK-Sonu: It's an `a`, not a `button` or `input`. And you shouldn't use `attr` to set *properties*. *AND* the OP said that `#btnSend` isn't unique (and has now been told it must be).

Comment: The title "How to find a button with custom attribute" of this question should be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already passing the button element into `fillenquiry` as its first argument, so just do

```
$(button).addClass("disabled");
```

...in that function (where `button` is whatever name you gave that first argument in the function) to add the Bootstrap ["disabled" class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#anchor-element-1).

Alternately, change the `a` to a `button type="button"`:

```
<button type="button" class='btn btn-orange' provider-id='$row->provider_id' id='btnSend' onclick='fillenquiry(this)'>Send Enquiry</button>
```

...and then

```
button.disabled = true;
```

---

> NOTE: actually there are multiple buttons with the same id,so I have to put the custom attribute as "provider-id".

If you really mean you're using `id="btnSend"` on more than one element, thats **invalid HTML**. `id` values **must** be unique. That said, it doesn't change the answer above, because we don't need to use the `id` to get the button instance.

You don't need to look up the button for this task, but if for some *other* reason you need to get the button instance, you can use an attribute selector:

```
var $button = $('[provider-id="some-id"]');
```

...and then either

```
$button.addClass("disabled");
```

for the `a` or

```
$button.prop("disabled", true);
```

for a `button`.

But again, you don't need it for this, since you're passing it into `fillenquiry`.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Thanks! Will fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('a[provider-id="some-id"]').attr('disabled',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `fillenquiry(this)` code to jquery click event

```
$('a[provider-id="some-id"]').click(function(e){
    /* paste fillenquiry() code here */
    $(this).unbind("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. beforeClose
   Called right after closing has been triggered but not yet started Note: If false is returned by the callback, the closing will be halted.
2. afterClose
   Called after closing animation has ended

The above methods you can find from fancybox documentation. This may help you.